# Access variable bitpositions in binary - Erlang

Tags: erlang

I'm new to erlang and have a probably simple question.

Let's say i have something like `A = [ 7, 203, 15, 11 ]` and a some binary `B`. Both `A` and `B` are generated at runtime.
Is there a simple way to check the bits in `B` by the positions described in `A`.
So the first bit to check would be 7, the next 203 and so on.

I realize that I could sort `A` and iterate through `B` until I'm at the positions within `A` but that seems a bit over the top for such a simple problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: ooops, already answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like the module below:

```
-module(bits).

-export([select/2]).

select(Pattern, Bitstring) -> select(Pattern, Bitstring, []).

select([], _, Acc) -> lists:reverse(Acc);
select([H | T], Bitstring, Acc) ->
    Pos = H - 1,
    <<_:Pos/bitstring, B:1/integer, _/bitstring>> = Bitstring,
    select(T, Bitstring, [B | Acc]).
```

Comment: Heh.. same match using recursion rather than a list comprehension.. But your version starts counting bits at 1, rather than 0..

Comment: Returns a list of integers and since it is Erlang I of course start counting at 1 :-)

Answer (score 0):

Example using list comprehension:

```
A=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]. 
B = <<"0123456789">>.

[begin 
  <<_:D/bits, Bit:1/bits, _/bits>> = B,
  Bit
 end
 || D <- A].
```

Gives:

```
[<<0:1>>,
 <<0:1>>,
 <<1:1>>,
 <<1:1>>,
 <<0:1>>,
 <<0:1>>,
 <<0:1>>,
 <<0:1>>]
```

Which is 0x30, i.e. '0'.

EDIT: bah, fixed bug...